# findByPropertyAndReleation not giving me the expected Entity

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm importing historical football (or soccer, if you're from the US) data into a Neo4j database using a spring boot application (2.1.6.RELEASE) with the `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j` dependency and a standalone, locally running 3.5.6 Neo4j database server.

But for some reason searching for an entity by a simple property and an attached, referenced entity, does not work, althought the relation is present in the database.

This is the part of the model, that is currently giving me a headache:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Season")
open class Season(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null,

    @Index(unique = true)
    var name: String,

    var seasonNumber: Long,

    @Relationship(type = "IN_LEAGUE", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    var league: League?,

    var start: LocalDate,

    var end: LocalDate
)

@NodeEntity(label = "League")
open class League(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null,

    @Index(unique = true)
    var name: String,

    @Relationship(type = "BELONGS_TO", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    var country: Country?
)
```

(I left out the Country class, as I'm pretty sure that it is not part of the problem)

To allow running the import more than once, I want to check if the corresponding entity is already present in the database and only import newer ones. So I added the following method SeasonRepository:

```
open class SeasonRepository : CrudRepository<Season, Long> {
    fun findBySeasonNumberAndLeague(number: Long, league: League): Season?
}
```

But it is giving me a `null` result instead of the existing entity on consecutive runs, hence I get duplicates in my database.

I would have expected spring-data-neo4j to reduce the passed `League` to its Id and then have a generated query that looks somewhat like this:

```
MATCH (s:Season)-[:IN_LEAGUE]->(l:League) WHERE id(l) = {leagueId} AND s.seasonNumber = {seasonNumber} WITH s MATCH (s)-[r]->(o) RETURN s,r,o
```

but when I turn on finer logging on the neo4j package I see this output in the log file:

```
MATCH (n:`Season`) WHERE n.`seasonNumber` = { `seasonNumber_0` } AND n.`league` = { `league_1` } WITH n RETURN n,[ [ (n)-[r_i1:`IN_LEAGUE`]->(l1:`League`) | [ r_i1, l1 ] ] ], ID(n) with params {league_1={id=30228, name=1. Bundesliga, country={id=29773, name=Deutschland}}, seasonNumber_0=1}
```

So for some reason, spring-data seems to think, that the league property is a simple / primitive property and not a full releation, that needs to be resolved by the id (`n.`league`= {`league_1`}`).

I only got it to work, by passing the id of the league, and providing a custom query using the `@Query` annotation but I actually thought, that it would work with spring-data-neo4j out of the box.

Any help appreciated. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Can you try a method just with findByLeague and see if this works?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I added the method `fun findByLeague(league : League) : List<Season>` but it is giving me an empty List. Running the query `MATCH (s:Season)-[:IN_LEAGUE]->(l:League) WHERE id(l) = 31214 RETURN s.name` is giving me 56 results (I copied the id 31214 of the league from the debugger). Yet again in the logs it seems, as if spring-data is trying to resolve the league as simple property: the query is exactly the same as in the original question, except the seasonNumber part is left out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data Neo4j does not support objects as parameters at the moment. It is possible to query for properties on related entities/nodes e.g. `findBySeasonNumberAndLeagueName` if this is a suitable solution.